Access array offset on value of type null
I recently noticed some warnings showing up in Drupal 7/Civi 5.78.3.
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in content_6714a2bcf3f5f1_28844565() (line 36 of /home/.../sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/54/42/fa/XX8d_0.file_CustomData.tpl.php).

Per Drupal, this warning occurs when accessing these locations:

/civicrm/contact/view/cd?reset=1&gid=16&cid=4271&selectedChild=custom_16&snippet=json&crmAngularModules=af,afCore,afSearchTasks,afsearchTabNote,afsearchTabRel,angularFileUpload,api4,checklist-model,crmDialog,crmResource,crmSearchDisplay,crmSearchDisplayTable,crmSearchTasks,crmUi,crmUtil,dialogService,ngSanitize,ui.bootstrap,ui.sortable
/civicrm/contact/view/cd?reset=1&gid=6&cid=3523&selectedChild=custom_6&snippet=json&crmAngularModules=af,afCore,afSearchTasks,afsearchTabNote,afsearchTabRel,angularFileUpload,api4,checklist-model,crmDialog,crmResource,crmSearchDisplay,crmSearchDisplayTable,crmSearchTasks,crmUi,crmUtil,dialogService,ngSanitize,ui.bootstrap,ui.sortable
/civicrm/contact/view/cd?reset=1&gid=8&cid=4271&selectedChild=custom_8&snippet=json&crmAngularModules=af,afCore,afSearchTasks,afsearchTabNote,afsearchTabRel,angularFileUpload,api4,checklist-model,crmDialog,crmResource,crmSearchDisplay,crmSearchDisplayTable,crmSearchTasks,crmUi,crmUtil,dialogService,ngSanitize,ui.bootstrap,ui.sortable

These warnings suggest something is going on with custom groups 16, 6, 8. For additional context, these custom groups are multifield tables which I also have on a civi webform. Everytime that form submits, it duplicates the table in each of these custom groups. I know that in the past, I have deleted an option value in one of the questions in custom group 16. I don't know if that has created a problem, but I can't seem to figure out where the NULL value is happening.
